# Get time from Xamarin Forms TimePicker

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timepicker

I'm developing an app in Xamarin for iOS and Android. I have a TimePicker in my XAML page. I'm invoking the picker using `.Focus()` method.

Since `TimePicker` doesn't have a `DateSelected` method, how do I get the value set in the popup? can someone shed some light as I couldn't figure out anywhere in their forums.

XAML

```
<TimePicker x:Name="datePicker" 
                WidthRequest="0" 
                HeightRequest="0"
                />
```

Code Behind

```
datePicker.Focus();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var timeSpan = datePicker.Time;
```

> `Time` Returns a TimeSpan. 
>   Gets or sets the displayed time. 
>   This is a bindable property.

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.TimePicker/